# Collect data at mian component of helper class functions return value in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have made a helper class , containing so many functions are to be called from different components, but i can't get the returned values at the main component from where the helper functions are get called? please help ..

```
    helper1: function(){
     console.log("ok Pressed");
    },
    checkIfRoomExist: function(param1, param2){
        console.log("userid", param2);
          firestore()
            .collection('userlist')
            .doc(param2)
            .get()
            .then(documentSnapshot => {
                console.log("room_id=>", documentSnapshot.data().room_id)
            })
            
    },
    helper3: function(param1, param2){

    }
}

export default helpers; `
 This is my helper class and i call it from my components and like
`import helper from './helper';`
Then Call the function and pass params like
`onPress={() => helper.checkIfRoomExist(param1, param2)}`
and now here i want the result of the checkIfRoomExist() function , how ?
```

Comment: please add some example or code.

Comment: sir, i edit the question please have a look..and please help ..

Answer (score 0):

this is example for functional component

```
helper1: function(){
     console.log("ok Pressed");
return "some_data"
    }

    checkIfRoomExist: function(param1, param2){
        console.log("userid", param2);
          firestore()
            .collection('userlist')
            .doc(param2)
            .get()
            .then(documentSnapshot => {
                console.log("room_id=>", documentSnapshot.data().room_id)
            })
            
    }
    helper3: function(param1, param2){

    }

// this is how you can export multiple function from a compoenent
export {helper1,checkIfRoomExist,helper3}


// This is my helper class and i call it from my components and like
import {helper1,checkIfRoomExist,helper3} from './helper';

onPress={async () => let my_return_data = await helper1()}
onPress={() => checkIfRoomExist(param1, param2)}
onPress={() => helper3(param1,parami2)}
```

//Class Component Examples

```
class helper {

   helper1: function(){
     console.log("ok Pressed");
    }

    checkIfRoomExist: function(param1, param2){
        console.log("userid", param2);
          firestore()
            .collection('userlist')
            .doc(param2)
            .get()
            .then(documentSnapshot => {
                console.log("room_id=>", documentSnapshot.data().room_id)
            })
            
    }
    helper3: function(param1, param2){

    }

}
// this is how you can export multiple function from a compoenent
export default helper


// This is my helper class and i call it from my components and like
import helper from './helper';

 
onPress={() => new helper().helper1()}
onPress={() => new helper().checkIfRoomExist(param1, param2)}
onPress={() => new helper().helper3(param1,parami2)}
```

Comment: I think you cant get my point what i am exactly want ? you just copy paste the code ... i questioned for how to get return data from main component??

Comment: did you want to return some data from those functions.??

Comment: yes , i want to access the returned data at main component where the helper functions are get called ...how sir?

Comment: ok. I have updated the answer. you have to return some-data and use async and await to get that data.